# Google Bigquery does not updating the permissions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Google Bigquery (big query.google.com) not able to update the access for individual users at dataset level. The default "Iam" permissions are overriding.

Even if you delete any existing permissions those are not removing from datasets. Again the removed users got the permissions by default.

Comment: looks like it is not a question. you might want to submit issue here -  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149 otherwise formulate a question!

Comment: Are you by any chance using some api client?

Comment: Are you using the web UI to edit permissions?

Comment: Hi William and Graham, I am using Browser UI to setting permissions. I am level i have provided all the permissions and Bigquery level not able to give.  Sometime it is working sometime it is not working. We dont have support model to raise a case with google.